# what is an alternate way to refer to HTML/JavaScript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Often I need to refer to code written in HTML/JavaScript/CSS, but it is a very awkward construction to constantly refer to the descriptive trio of 'HTML/JavaScript/CSS' code.

for example, Mozilla refers to its HTML/JavaScript/CSS JetPack code as 'a JetPack'.

Other than the defunct 'dHTML', what are some concise, generic and accurate terms I can use to collectively refer to applications written in HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

Comment: Call it Web 2.0, it always impresses the suits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Web application** is perhaps too loose of a term, but it's a start.

Let's break it down.

1. HTML is data, CSS is presentation, and JavaScript is code.  These are **web technologies**.
2. These are usually brought together by a **browser**.
3. Something in a browser on the web is a **website**.
4. JavaScript suggests it is somewhat interactive, so it's not just a site, it's an **application**.

("Application" also suggests that it's more complex, like with a SQL backend or something, so you might sound even more talented. :)

I'm guessing that you had the term LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP) in mind?  To my knowledge there is no such abbreviation for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  The easiest way to say it is to just say it.

Versus "Front end" – I think that term implies that you built something that customers used.  "Web application" is nonspecific about who the users are, so it would apply to customer-facing applications as well as internal-use applications.  The word "application" implies that it's not just a tool; there are users who are not the programmers.  "Front end" is probably more impressive because a customer-facing application has to be nicer than an internal one.

If you are not using it in a browser, or it's not actually on *the* web, maybe just your intranet or an internally distributed application bundle, it's still an **application developed with web technologies**.

Comment: What if I am not using HTML/JavaScript/CSS in a web context, i.e. not in a browser?

Comment: I agree with James - HTML/JavaScript/CSS are not quite exactly web technologies, and I think I disagree slightly with #4 - JavaScript can be (and is often, these days) used to facilitate sites without really becoming an "application."

Comment: @james - How else are you using HTML/JS/CSS, if not in a browser?

Comment: These techs can be used outside of a traditional web page (e.g. webOS), and a "web application" doesn't just mean a web page with some css and javascript. DHTML is good.

Comment: @K Prime - Imagine you use, say, WebKit purely as a rendering engine  and not in a web browser.  That rendering engine can get its HTML/JavaScript/CSS from any source, not just a web server.

Comment: I am going to mark this the correct answer because as Kevin points out: "there is no such abbreviation for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The easiest way to say it is to just say it."

Comment: "@james - How else are you using HTML/JS/CSS, if not in a browser?"

FYI- Check this out: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.1/manuals/p4jsapi/index.html

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to have to say **DHTML** anyway.  Why would you say it's "defunct"? It is the perfect answer to this question.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHTML. DHTML means Dynamic HTML—which is exactly what the combination of HTML/JavaScript/CSS code is.

Unless you're dealing with someone who isn't impressed with terms that are less than a year or two old, or unless you aren't specifically talking about code, DHTML conveys exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: Sadly, even the wikipedia article says "The term has fallen out of use in recent years"

Answer (score 6):

Given that the person you're trying to convey this message to knows you're talking about web-related stuff - `Front-end` or `Front-end development` has always worked for me.

Comment: Maybe you could say `Front-end Assets` to refer to HTML/CSS/JS

Answer (score 4):

"HTML5" is the answer I now believe to be correct to replace "HTML/JavaScript/CSS".  Since I asked the question in January, HTML5 has gained a lot more recognition for its incredible capabilities and promise.  "HTML5" also has significantly greater name recognition than 7 months ago, and clearly sets it apart from lesser HTML.

Answer (score 3):

**Web Suite**

> `suite: a set of things belonging together, in particular.`

thus you have:

> `Web Suite: the set of HTML/CSS/JavaScript, the basic technologies used to develop a web site or application.`

example:

`"I used the Web Suite to make a cool website to show off all my pictures of cats sitting in boxes."`

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason there's no specific term is the same reason that dHTML fell into disrepute - all three scripts are so integral to frontend development that there ceases to be a need to refer to them specifically. If you code in HTML, you almost necessarily use CSS, and if you have any active content at all it will most probably be in JavaScript.

Frontend development is a bit vague, but something like HTML based frontend development should get your point across.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refer to an application - use Web Application.
And if you need to refer to some code - use simple JS (JavaScript) because most of your code (except for some ie css expressions if you use it) will be in JS, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

**Web code**

I was just having to write "HTML/Javascript/CSS" in an email and thought, "Isn't there a better term for this?". Googling, I found this post. I'm going with "web code".

Answer (score 1):

"UX" (User Experience) or "Front-end Development."

Comment: That's very unspecific and can equally well be used to refer to natve, rich-client applications.

Comment: You can't really be that specific when you limit yourself to a couple of words.

Answer (score 1):

*Web Applications*, and *Web 2.0* are both big names.  One name/acronym that I personally like to use is *RIA*, or [Rich Internet Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application).  From the article:

> Rich Internet Applications (RIAs) are
>   web applications that have most of the
>   characteristics of desktop
>   applications, typically delivered
>   either by way of a standards based web
>   browser, via a browser plug-in, or
>   independently via sandboxes or virtual
>   machines.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application) Examples of RIA
>   frameworks include Ajax, Curl, GWT,
>   Adobe Flash/Adobe Flex/AIR,
>   Java/JavaFX,[2] Mozilla's XUL,
>   OpenLaszlo and Microsoft
>   Silverlight.[3]

Also, someone else mentioned "impressing the suits," which this title tends to do.  After all, it's got "rich" right in the name ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some call it a JAM stack, which stands for Javascript, API and Markup. But I acknowledge that it's not as specific as LAMP or something like that.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack
https://jamstack.org/

Comment: This isn't right. [**JAMStack**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlify#Jamstack), a term invented by [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/jamstack/), refers very explicitly to an infrastructure where static front-end files (Markup, Styles and Scripts) are pulled off a CDN and the back-end, so far as it exists, only exists as remote services accessed through APIs.

Answer (score 0):

However uncool it might be, it is still *DHTML* to me.

They are standard *web technologies* for producing *dynamic websites* and *web applications*. The last thing we need is another vacuous moniker for something that is more than adequately described by DHTML.